# Giving td bgcolor depends on a condition

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to give a `bgcolor` inside `<td>` depends on a condition

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
   $('.asoy').append('<tbody><tr><td>' + (angka++) + '</td> <td>' + val.transdate + '</td>' + '<td class="satu">' + val.salespos + '</td><td class="dua">' + val.omset + '</td><td class="dynamic"></td> </tr></tbody>');
   if ($(".satu").text() == $(".dua").text()) {
     $(".dynamic").css('background-color', 'red');
   } else {
     $(".dynamic").css('background-color', 'green');
   }
 });
```

and here is my HTML

```
<table class="asoy table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>Omset</td>
      <td>Sales XML</td>
      <td>Tanggal</td>
      <td>Status</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

with my script above i only get `green` i have try to `.html()` and `.val()` it's not helping. sorry for my bad english.

My fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hku73vs2/

Comment: can you show demo of what it looks like after append?

Comment: @guradio here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hku73vs2/

Comment: Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hku73vs2/1/

Comment: @YVS1102 check this updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hku73vs2/3/) you need to specify the row you compare and the dynamic class of that row. by using `$(this).find(".dynamic")` , `$(this).find(".dua")` and `$(this).find(".satu")` you will get same row

Answer (score 2):

As you are adding multiple rows, you need to limit the scope of your jquery selectors

`$(".satu")` will find all `.satu`, not just the one for the current row (excluding the `tbody` append)- and `$(".satu").text()` will give the first row's text every time.

To get the current html, reverse the `append` to `appendTo`, ie change:

```
var html = '<tr><td>' + (angka++) + '</td> <td>' ...
$(".asoy").append(html)
```

to:

```
var html = '<tr><td>' + (angka++) + '</td> <td>' ...
var row = $(html).appendTo(".asoy");
```

you can then use row:

```
if ($(".satu", row).text() == $(".dua", row).text())
    $(".dynamic", row).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hku73vs2/1/

---

Alternatively, you can use the data directly and forget about the jquery:

```
var color = "green";
if (val.salespos == val.omset)
    color = "red";

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $('.asoy').append('....<td class="dynamic" style="background-color:' + color + '"></td></tr>');
```

(as an aside, you could also use a class for this and addClass rather than change the style)

Comment: the latest script so simple . never think that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this also :

```
var htmloutp = '';

$.each(data, function(key, val){
    htmloutp += '<tr><td>'+ (angka++) +'</td> <td>' + val.transdate + '</td>' + '<td class="satu">' + val.salespos + '</td><td class="dua">' + val.omset + '</td><td class="dynamic" style="background-color : ' + (val.salespos == val.omset ? 'red' : 'green' ) + '"></td></tr>'
});    

$('tbody').html(htmloutp); //add tbody in html
```